# Chinese character encoding with differenct operation systems/languages

Tags: r, excel, encoding

I am having trouble read my csv file containing simplified Chinese character into my r. I have tried the encoding=utf-8,gb18130,gb2130 etc. The Chinese character could be not displayed.

> I also tried change the encoding by excel to utf8 csv, no luck.
>   I also
>   tried using Chinese windows and set the **locale** to China. No luck.
>
> After I change to Chinese windows. The excel can open my csv (English
>   windows cannot open it correctly). The r studio can open it in the
>   View() but the R console console could not read my csv even if I
>   reinstall the r as Chinese version.
>
> I tried the Ubuntu, Ubuntu could not even read my csv at all. At least in Windows, the R studio can read my data well.
>
> I tried google sheet. But my file is so big that Google sheet would
>   not even open it
>
> I tired Cals in Ubuntu and convert it GB* since GB is
>   working fine in Windows R studio. No luck. And it takes more than 10
>   minutes to convert my 200Mb-750Mb data to gb18013

Comment: If you deal with Chinese character a lot. I suggest you stick to Chinese Windoes, it would make life so much easier most of the time.

Comment: Good point. I am tring to have Windows in Chinese and Ubuntu in English.

Comment: Why my excel can open my csv but my access cannot open it correctly?

Comment: In the access, you can specify the encoding method. Chose any encoding start with Simplified Chinese G*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu use UTF-8 as default Chinese Encoding. So you should encode it as UTF-8 instead GB18130 or other GB starting encoding.

- (1) Download Open Office (free and fast to install, have have higher
  file size than Cals in Ubuntu).
- (2) Detect your CSV encoding. Simply open your csv using Open office and choose an encoding method that display your Chinese character.
- (3) Save your csv to the correct encoding according to your
  operation system. Default Windows encoding is GBK for Chinese and Ubuntu is UTF8.

This should solve your file size problem and encoding problem. You do not even have to force the encoding. Normal `read.csv` would work.